# NodeJS : How do I unit test an Async function that depends on other Async calls

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs, sinon

I have a service that I inject a mongoose model into and then this service is used by my express routes to do certain functions. I have been stumped by how to unit test the below code, as there are multiple async calls to retrieve DB data to make some calculations and then return the result.

I am new to async unit testing and am using Jest runner with sinon.

```
// Service.ts
export default class Service {
    constructor(private dbModel){}

    public async problemFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        // validate args
        let data1;
        let data2;
        let data3;
        try {
            data1 = await SomeOtherService1.getData();
        }
        catch(e) {
            return e;
        }
        try {
            data2 = await SomeOtherService2.getData();
        }
        catch(e) {
            return e;
        }

        try {
            data3 = await this.dbModel
                    .findById(arg1)
                    .where('some_field')
                    .exists(false);
        }
        catch(e) {
            return e;
        }

        const calcResult = CalculationService.calc(arg1, data1, data2, data3);

        if (calcResult) {
            await this.dbModel.findByIdAndUpdate(arg1, calcResult);
            return this.dbModel.findById(arg1);
        } else {
            return new Error('Fail');
        }
    }
}
```

It would be most helpful if someone could explain how to unit test such a complex (in my opinion complex) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Syntax issues

If it's only a syntax issue, you can use mocha as following:

```
describe('my test suite', () => {

    it('should return valid data', async () => {
         let service = new Service();
         let res = await service.problemFunc({...});
         expect(res).to.equal(...);
    });
});
```

If you expect your `problemFunc` to throw an error you should use the npm module `chaiAsPromised` because it's an async function (return a promise).

---

### External dependencies specs

Here you've multiple external dependencies with business logic mixed together. In order to test such external dependencies you should use dependency injection.

You pass the external dependencies throught the constructor of your Service class.

```
constructor(private externalService1, private externalService2){
    this.externalService1 = externalService1;
    this.externalService2 = externalService2;
}
```

Then your method should look like this:

```
async problemFunc() {
    let data1 = await this.externalService1.getData();
    let data2 = await this.externalService2.getData();
}
```

Therefore you can mock the external dependencies in your test suite:

```
describe('my test suite', () => {

    it('should return valid data', async () => {
         let fakeDb1 = {
             getData: () => { return {}; }
         }

         let fakeDb2 = {
             getData: () => { return {}; }
         }
         let service = new Service(fakeDb1, fakeDb2);
         let res = await service.problemFunc({...});
         expect(res).to.equal(...);
    });
});
```

This list of well written articles can be helpful:
https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/06/29/test-induced-design-damage-or-why-tdd-is-so-painful/